# How do i set a vb form's size to fill the computer screen, and have all components in that form attapt to the size?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can I set the size of a form in Visual Basic 8 to the computers size, and also have all components in it adapt to the computers size?

I have set `WindowState` to maximized, but the components won't resize to the computer screens size.

Comment: There is not "The screen size". I have 3 screens all with a different size.

Comment: Try the `Anchor` property

Comment: Unlike Web pages and WPF controls, Winform controls do not do this automatically, you will have to write code to explicitly resize every element as you see fit.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that WPF Controls (rather than Windows Forms Controls) are designed to do.

Comment: The `Anchor` and `Dock` properties are what you need.

Comment: In addition to Anchor/Dock, look at the Tablelayoutpanel and the Flowlayoutpanel.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?630636-Anchor-amp-Dock-For-Automatic-Resizing&highlight=

Comment: You can use a 3rd party control like C1Sizer from Componentone Studio.